# css list for multiple elements

Tags: css, list

I have a page that I would like to use different `<ul>` and `<li>` settings for, for different elements but I'm not sure how.

In example "A" the indents/bullets aren't working properly but the image indent is:

> [image]

The Css for the layout "A" is here:

```css
ul.list{
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

In example "B" the indents/bullets are working properly but the image indent is.

> [image]

The CSS for the layout "B" is here:

```css
ul.list{
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    color:#fff;
}
ul {
    text-indent:0px; 
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

I would like to set a different CSS value for the text content than the graphic content.

Answer (score 0):

Specificity is your friend. If you have two elements you want to style differently you need to target them individually. The easiest way to do this is an id.